# Python type aliases without typing module TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.5

I was previously using `from typing import Dict, List` etc. but saw https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html give example type aliases as

> ```
> ConnectionOptions = dict[str, str]
> Address = tuple[str, int]
> Server = tuple[Address, ConnectionOptions]
> ```

When I tried in my own code

```
MyType = list[tuple[int, list[int]]]
```

I got

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Is it still not possible to use lowercase type names for typehints? If it is, how can I successfully do it?

Comment: It's available from python 3.9

Comment: @martineau why did you edit the tags

Comment: Because the `typing` module wasn't added until Python 3.5.